# Does convergence in probability imply continuity?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Assume I have a set of measures $\{\mu_k\}_{k\in \mathbb N} \in \mathcal P(\mathbb R^n)$ and a measure $\mu \in  \mathcal P(\mathbb R^n)$ where $\mu_k$ converges weakly to $\mu$, i.e. $\mu_k \rightharpoonup \mu$. Then say we have a function $f$ on  $\mathcal P(\mathbb R^n)$ and we have that $f(\mu_k)$ converges to $f(\mu)$ in probability. Does that also imply that $f$ is continuous?

I.e. can I follow from $f(\mu_k) \xrightarrow{p} f(\mu)$ when $\mu_k \rightharpoonup \mu$ that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: maybe if quantified over all such measures?  seems unlikely if we just have the one

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Take the very stupid example of $\mu_k \rightharpoonup \mu$: where $\mu_k = \mu$ for all $k$. In that case, we know nothing about $f$.

Comment: Ah. What if $f(\mu_k) \xrightarrow{p} f(\mu)$ for $\textit{all}$ sequences of measures that fulfill $\mu_k \rightharpoonup \mu$?